# Server can ping to but can NOT bet pinged by other server

Tags: networking

I got a quite basic question since I am just a programmer who have no idea how to deal with this kind of problem.

The company has 2 server (let's call them server A and server B) and I can ping those two server from my pc.

Server A can ping server B, server B however can NOT ping server A.

Server A and B details

- both are using Windows Server 2008 R2
- windows firewall are OFF for Domain, Private and Public profile
- same subnet mask
- different default gateway (but the first 3 digit are the same) xx.x.yy.yyy and xx.x.z.zzz

Any idea why this happened?

Thanks

Comment: You say the two machines have different default gateway settings.  This is usually because they are on different subnets - can you confirm this is the case here? If yes, then what device(s) (and how many) are sitting between the two servers?  Could that device be filtering out ICMP Ping traffic? A traceroute would be useful here - Windows command-line is `tracert aa.bb.cc.dd` where aa.bb.cc.dd is the IP address of the target machine.

Comment: Both subnet mask are 255.255.255.0. I tried with tracert from A to B and this is what I got (I wrote 'x' since they all are the same for both A and B) 
1. <1ms 322ms <1ms xx.x.3.254 (Server A gateway)
2. 1ms  <1ms <1ms xx.x.3.1
3. 1ms <1ms 1ms serverB [xx.x.14.103] (server B IP)
tracert from B to A
1. <1ms <1ms <1ms xx.x.14.1 (I have no idea what is this number)
2. timeout
3. timeout
and so on

Comment: xx.x.14.1 is most likely the LAN interface of the same router that has interface xx.x.3.1.  Bear in mind that traceroute will normally reports the IP address of "this side" of each hop in the chain.  So in your second traceroute (B to A) the first hop xx.x.14.1 is probably the "B-facing" LAN interface of the router with IP addresses xx.x.3.1.  If you check B's network config, its default gateway should be xx.x.14.1, yes?  Secondly, the fact that the traceroute dies after this hop, suggests that the problem lies between xx.x.14.1 and xx.x.3.254. My hunch is xx.x.3.254 could be blocking ICMP.